# What am I doing wrong in textfield Did End Editting?? Currency Formatting

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter, currency-formatting

So a part of the code looks like

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSNumber *currency = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.SalesAmounttext.text doubleValue]]; 

  self.SalesAmounttext.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:currency];

}
```

The above code means if I enter 499 in the textfield, the text will be converted into $499.00. If I clear the ENTIRE textfield, and re-enter another number, let's say 599, the text will be converted to $599.00. These are all the correct and expected behaviours.

However, if I happen to backspace $599.00 to only $ or $5 and then enter a new number such as 509 and leave the textfield, my textfield output becomes $0.00. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with:

```
[self.SalesAmounttext.text doubleValue]
```

This only gives a valid value if the text has no formatting, no currency symbol, no grouping characters, and a period for the decimal separator. If that is not all true it returns 0.

You need to convert the existing text to a `double` by using the currency formatter to parse the text.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSNumber *current = [formatter numberFromString:self.SalesAmounttext.text];
    if (!current) {
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        current = [formatter2 numberFromString:self.SalesAmounttext.text];
    }

    self.SalesAmounttext.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:current];
}
```

You probably need some additional checking to deal with invalid numbers.

Comment: I've just implemented your code. Now the entire textfield is empty every time I finish editing.

Comment: As I said, you probably need further checking. Most likely if your just enter a plain number, the currency formatter will fail. I'll update my answer a bit.

Comment: OK, I added another check. This should handle values that are already a valid currency value as well as plainly entered numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The `doubleValue` method will return 0 if you pass anything other than a valid number as the first character. From the docs:

"The floating-point value of the receiver’s text as a double. Returns **HUGE_VAL** or **–HUGE_VAL** on overflow, 0.0 on underflow. Returns 0.0 if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid text representation of a floating-point number."

So you can do something like:

```
NSString *newString = [self.SalesAmounttext.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
```

and pass in the newString to the formatter.

Comment: It's more complicated than this. Depending on the user's locale, the results of what you propose could be something like `5 000,50` or some other formatted decimal that the `doubleValue` method can't handle.